# Wordpress - Shortcode inside shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I try to make a shortcode like

```
add_shortcode( 'test', 'test' );
function test( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $html = '<div>'.do_shortcode( $content ).'</div>';
    return $html;
}
```

I try some thing like `[test][test]this is test[/test][/test]` But that not working.

[image]

How to fix that. Thanks

Comment: can you post code?

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of the shortcode parser.

You can check out [this entry from the Codex on the shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Nested_Shortcodes), where it says:

> However the parser will fail if a shortcode macro is used to enclose
>   another macro of the same name:
>
> ```
> [tag-a]   
>     [tag-a]    
>     [/tag-a] 
>  [/tag-a]
> ```
>
> This is a limitation of the context-free regexp parser used by do_shortcode() - it is  very fast but does not count levels of nesting, so it can't match each opening tag with its correct closing tag in these cases.

Comment: birgire is right. You can use it like this [test][test_a]content here[/test_a][/test]